# How get pid of a subprocess created with the same name of calling process?

Tags: delphi, subprocess, pid

I'm wanting get pid of second instance of a process where this second instance have same name of calling process. How do this?

Eg:

a classical example is Google Chrome ( several instances with same name "chrome.exe" )  see below.

[image]

I have used this code following but i is getting pid only of calling process:

```
Function ProcessIDFromAppname32( appname: String ): DWORD;
  Var
    snapshot: THandle;
    processEntry : TProcessEntry32;
  Begin
    Result := 0;
    appName := UpperCase( appname );
    snapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
                  TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,
                  0 );
    If snapshot <> 0 Then
    try
      processEntry.dwSize := Sizeof( processEntry );
      If Process32First( snapshot, processEntry ) Then
      Repeat
        If Pos(appname,
               UpperCase(ExtractFilename(
                             StrPas(processEntry.szExeFile)))) > 0
        Then Begin
          Result:= processEntry.th32ProcessID;
          Break;
        End; 
      Until not Process32Next( snapshot, processEntry );
    finally
      CloseHandle( snapshot );
    End; 
  End;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `break` that terminates iteration. That way you will find all matching processes. Obviously you'll need to return a list of process IDs instead of a single one, but I presume you know how to do that.

Comment: you can edit your answer with a code example getting only second instance please? Thank you.

Comment: You just want the second instance. Well, ignore the first, and return in the second match. Use a variable to count. Do you know how to declare an integer variable. Do you know how to increment one. Do you know how to test if it is equal to a specific value.

Comment: I also wonder if you understand anything about the existing code. If you did then I'd expect you to be able to do this yourself. If you don't understand it then you are just asking us to spoon feed you code. Are you prepared to try to learn something new?